# Got notification about voting in Moderator Election when it ended

Tags: bug, status-planned

I got a notification about voting in the community moderator election, however when I went to the page, it had actually ended, both 1 hour ago.

Is this due to the voting [being skipped](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/992/2018-community-moderator-election-results)?

[image]

Comment: Yes it is. (Padding due to minimum comment length)

Comment: @Chalmondley Nominations were open from the 22nd.  But I don't recall receiving a notification about that.

Comment: @Chalmondley There was most definitely a notification that it is possible to nominate yourself (you need >300rep for that). As we had only one member that volunteered after a self-nomination period of 7 days, it seems fairly fair to skip voting directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was my fault and something I need to fix our process. In a perfect world, the election would automatically be ended if there aren't enough candidates. Unfortunately, that bit is still a manual process. In the future, I plan to push back the start of the voting portion a few minutes before it's supposed to start if it looks as if it won't be necessary. Then, if there aren't enough candidates, I can end the election so there won't be a notification. (I'd also need to remove the community event in the sidebar at that time.)

I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Chalmondley Nominations can be made an entire week long and I have gotten a notification to nominate myself. You only have enough reputation to vote, this is why you weren't notified for the nomination period.

Answer (score 4):

There is always a notification box and link on the main page. There was a week for self nomination, another week for candidate questioning.

If there had been more than one candidate there would have been a week for voting. However since this is a pro tempore election with only one candidate it ends as soon as voting is opened. (in this case it actually took abt 20-30 minutes as it is still manual)

Comment: It was still pretty annoying. One candidate or not, I would have liked a chance to vote for @CareyGregory

Comment: It was indeed a surprise for anyone unfamiliar with the procedure. But unlike presidential or brexit, this one turned out as satisfactory result.  –– One thing about notification might be added here, if I understood correctly: direct notifications were sent out to those with enough rep to be eligible to vote?

Comment: @LangLangC - You usually get a notification in your inbox (The box icon in the top bar).

Comment: I meant: announcement/nomination [needs 150 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work) to get notification? The exact date for the "voting" passed by with me just AFK, 18h ago (no number for that in the topbar box) and the other "election news" was just 22 Oct "nominations begin". Wasn't there another one? (I feel the inbox is a bit shaky these days.)

Comment: Ah. The 'surprise' bit was also due to me misreading Jon's announcement of "On October 29, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate." Somehow I went home after Carey's nomination expecting a voting phase (to show how much support the candidate and the site has, even if the (f)actual result would be the same). So the 'surprise' bit should mostly just apply to people suffering bouts of dyslexic reading incomprehension like I did here.

Comment: But if you don't visit the main page often, you would see that notification that nominations were open.  I certainly didn't, a notification like the one saying it was over would get a bit more attention.